# Strange CSS precedence behavior after AJAX load

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am trying to figure out how I seem to be losing my CSS precedence on an AJAX loaded page. I am loading my custom CSS last on the main page, so that should allow my CSS to override any bootstrap CSS. After loading new content via AJAX, bootstrap is overwriting my custom CSS. I can see via browser debug that bootstrap has overwritten the property.

Custom CSS Styling:

```
.mytableclass td {
font-size: small;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

As bootstrap isn't setting the font-size or text-align, it applies fine, but my vertical-align is overridden. I am not loading the CSS files again in the AJAX loaded page. There has to be some sort of reason, but after several hours I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the relative html for this issue?  Also, have you tried using `!important`?

Comment: Whether CSS is loaded via Ajax or not doesn't make a difference; it's probably just plain old CSS specificity that is foiling you. We'd have to see a sample bootstrap ruleset + your ruleset to explain why.

Comment: I can get around the problem easily enough by just adding my own class to all the td rows, but that is a bit of work for something that shouldn't be behaving as it is.

Just to clarify, the CSS is loaded before the AJAX loads. I am not sure what you mean by a ruleset. It is my understanding that the last CSS file loaded will take precedence when applying the CSS. As far as I know, that should be only thing that matters.

What would you like to see specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post the Bootstrap CSS class definition, I'm going to guess it is a CSS selector priority issue.

Is the Bootstrap CSS selector more specific than yours? [Then it gets priority over any CSS loaded later](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Either make your selector as specific or more specific, or apply the !important directive, but that is not recommended (also see [ITCSS](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/manage-large-css-projects-itcss-101517528)).

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to work on it and answer at the same time. From the responses I managed to figure it out. Bootstrap was getting the styling from table-bordered. This was a class in my table. I had copied and pasted it from another page and completely forgot it was there. Adding table-bordered.mytableclass in my custom CSS resolved the issue. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a specific bit of CSS after everything else does not give it any precedence. What you'll want to do is make sure it has a more specific selector. (You could also use `!important`, but that a hack and I don't recommend it unless you can't get anything else to work.

If `.mytableclass td` is the selector bootstrap uses, consider adding something to the front of it. ie `body .mytableclass td`. Or you can go into the HTML itself and add an id that you only use as a selector in the AJAX CSS.

Comment: Bootstrap selectors:

`table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;`

Comment: @RandAl'Thor, your best bet will be to give it a custom class or id to use. If you can't get at the HTML code, try prepending the selector with `body` or something.